# Módulos em Rust

Tags: rust

A estrutura do meu projeto está assim:

```
src/main.rs
--- game.rs
--- game_state.rs
```

Dentro de `game.rs` tem:

```
mod game_state;
```

E dentro de `game_state.rs` tem

```
mod game;
```

Porém isso me retorna um erro:
file not found for module `game_state`

Answer (score 5):

Se você deseja que `game.rs` e `game_state.rs` fiquem no mesmo diretório raiz de `main.rs`, você deve declarar os módulos no própio arquivo `main.rs`.

```
// src/main.rs

mod game;
mod game_state;
```

Módulos só podem referenciar submódulos se os mesmos forem diretórios, portanto, caso você declare o submódulo `mod game_state;` no arquivo `game.rs`, é preciso criar o diretório `game/`, mover o arquivo `game.rs` para `game/mod.rs` e criar um novo arquivo/módulo `game/game_state.rs`.

```
src/game/
    └──── mod.rs
    └──── game_state.rs
src/main.rs
```

Apesar de ser bastante flexível, a estrutura de módulos da linguagem Rust é um pouco confusa e intimidadora mas já há [discussões](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2126) que tentam melhorar essa situação.

Answer (score 1):

Todo import de arquivo vai ao arquivo principal, ou seja, o *parente* de todos:

**main.rs**

```rust
mod game;
mod game_state;
```

Para se referir à `game` dentro de `game_state`, pode usar:

**game_state.rs**

```rust
use super::game;
```

Ou seja, o mesmo de acessar o módulo parente (`main.rs` de fato é um módulo).

Se quiser sub-módulos semelhantes à `main.rs`, que podem importar outros arquivos, crie uma pasta, tipo:

```
/src/
└── ./game_state/
      └── ./mod.rs
```

Answer (score 0):

> Porém isso me retorna um erro: file not found for module game_state

Essa estrutura espera um arquivo em: `game_state/game.rs`