# Para que serve lib.rs em Rust?

Tags: característica-linguagem, rust

Como mostrado [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/270719/m%C3%B3dulos-em-rust), em Rust é possível importar um arquivo (suas structs, funções, etc) usando a palavra chave `mod`. Por exemplo, na seguinte estrutura de diretórios:

```
src/
    main.rs
    minhasfuncoes.rs
```

Eu posso acessar as funções escritas em `minhasfuncoes.rs` adicionando `mod minhasfuncoes` no topo do arquivo `main.rs`.

No entanto, lendo na internet vi que é comum criar um arquivo chamado `lib.rs` no diretório quando se cria um pacote. Para que serve esse arquivo `lib.rs`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O arquivo `lib.rs` é o *entry-point* convencional de bibliotecas escritas em Rust.

Todos os [itens](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items.html) (funções, estruturas, enumerações, *traits*, etc) exportados nesse *entry-point* podem ser acessados por outras Crates que dependem da sua biblioteca.

Quando uma Crate utiliza outra Crate como biblioteca (isso se chama dependência), somente os itens públicos de `lib.rs` podem ser acessados. Como, por padrão, os itens de um módulo em Rust são privados, somente o que é explicitamente marcado como `pub` em `lib.rs` é visível para os dependentes *downstream*. Itens privados também não aparecem na documentação gerada automaticamente em [docs.rs](https://docs.rs/).

Uma Crate pode ser um binário ou uma biblioteca. Forma-se uma “árvore de dependências” quando Crates começam a depender de outras Crates. O gerenciamento de dependências é feito pelo Cargo.

Geralmente bibliotecas *open-source* são publicadas no [crates.io](https://crates.io/), mas esse não é o único meio de disponibilizar uma Crate. Além de depender de bibliotecas publicadas no crates.io, é possível também especificar repositórios Git, projetos locais ou em outros *registries* como *library sources*. Veja mais [aqui](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies).

Para mais detalhes sobre bibliotecas e sobre o Cargo, o [Livro Oficial do Cargo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/index.html) é uma boa referência.

---

Por padrão, quando você utiliza o comando `cargo new` para criar um projeto, cria-se um arquivo `main.rs` no diretório `src`. Isso indica que o projeto é uma Crate executável (também chamada de *binary crate*). O arquivo `main.rs` contém a função `main` que é executada quando alguém inicia seu binário.

Já quando se utiliza a *flag* `--lib` para gerar um novo projeto, cria-se, ao invés de `main.rs`, `lib.rs`, o que define o projeto como uma biblioteca. O `lib.rs` é, reiterando, o *entry-point* dos itens exportados pela biblioteca.

O Rust optou por estabelecer convenções bem definidas, de modo que, por padrão, todo projeto com um `lib.rs` é considerado uma biblioteca e todo projeto com um `main.rs` é considerado um executável. Essas convenções podem ser alteradas, mas isso é raramente necessário.

Se necessário, um binário e um executável podem coexistir numa mesma Crate.

É possível também criar um [Workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html), ideal para [*monorepos*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/452607/69296), mas aí já vai além do escopo desta pergunta.