# Qual a diferença entre mod e use em Rust?

Tags: característica-linguagem, rust

Eu entendo o funcionamento da palavra-chave `mod`, explicado [nesta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/270719/m%C3%B3dulos-em-rust). Para usuários do Python, `mod` funciona exatamente como a palavra-chave `import`. Isto é, para usar as funções e outros objetos definidas em um arquivo `foo.rs`, basta adicionar, no topo de `main.rs`, o comando `mod foo`.

No entanto, essa constatação me causou uma certa confusão porque, até então, eu acreditava que a palavra-chave `use` era o equivalente no Rust de `import` no Python.

Inclusive, quando tento fazer o mesmo procedimento acima com `use`, deparo-me com o seguinte erro:

```
1 | use foo;
  |     ^^^^^ no external crate `foo`
```

Para que serve o palavra-chave `use`, então?

Comment: Não, você não entendeu, `use` é parecido como `import`  em Python, mas não é exatamente igual. `mod` não tem equivalente me Python porque o mecanismo se parece mas não é igual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `mod`

A palavra-chave `mod` **declara** um módulo em Rust. Módulos são utilizados para controlar **escopo** e **privacidade**. Para uma introdução ao conceito de módulos, veja [aqui](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html).

O `mod` pode ser utilizada de dois modos diferentes para criar módulos:

1. **Definindo, explicitamente, um bloco**

   ```
   //# Arquivo `main.rs`

   mod math {
       pub fn add(a: i64, b: i64) -> i64 { a + b }
       pub fn sub(a: i64, b: i64) -> i64 { add(a, -b) }
   }

   // Podemos utilizar `math::add` e `math::sub` aqui.
   ```

   Acima, criamos um novo módulo, qualificado como `math`. De fora desse módulo, para utilizar uma de suas funções expostas, é necessário utilizar o nome do módulo.

   Repare que, dentro de `math`, é possível referir à função `add` somente como `add` (como fiz para implementar a função `sub`). Mas, de fora do módulo, como disse acima, é necessário utilizar `math::add`.
2. **Definindo via outro arquivo**

   ```
   //# Arquivo `math.rs`

   pub fn add(a: i64, b: i64) -> i64 { a + b }
   pub fn sub(a: i64, b: i64) -> i64 { add(a, -b) }
   ```

   E:

   ```
   //# Arquivo `main.rs`:

   mod math;

   // Podemos utilizar `math::add` e `math::sub` aqui.
   ```

   Note que, sob a perspectiva do `main.rs`, nada mudou. Nele, assim como no exemplo anterior, definiu-se um novo módulo, qualificado como `math`. A diferença é o local em que o conteúdo do módulo foi definido.

   No caso, quando a diretiva `mod` é utilizada sem definir um bloco explicitamente, ela criará um novo módulo com o nome fornecido e buscará o conteúdo do módulo em um arquivo com nome correspondente.

   Repare que o módulo *não* é definido no arquivo `math.rs`. Ou seja, o arquivo `math.rs` **não** é a definição de um módulo. Isso é frequentemente um ponto de confusão no Rust já que algumas linguagens (como JavaScript) operam diferentemente. A definição do módulo ocorre em `main.rs`, através da diretiva `mod math`.

Com isso, podemos concluir que um módulo em Rust é criado pela diretiva `mod`. O conteúdo do arquivo pode ser definido diretamente, com um bloco seguindo `mod <name>`. Também pode ser definido no arquivo de `<name>.rs`.

---

## `use`

A diretiva `use` é, quando aliada ao `mod`, um ponto de confusão. Em muitas linguagens (como JavaScript e Python), o conceito de módulos geralmente associa-se a uma única palavra-chave, como `import`. Rust adota uma abordagem um pouco diferente e, por isso, pode parecer "estranho". Mas na verdade é bem simples. Vejamos...

Já vimos que um módulo pode ser definido utilizando a palavra-chave `mod`. A partir desse momento, poderemos acessar o conteúdo do módulo utilizando um [**caminho de módulo**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-03-paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree.html).

Nos exemplos anteriores, de `main.rs`, o caminho para chegar à função `sum`, do módulo `math`, é `math::sum`. Se existissem vários módulos aninhados (o que é comum em Rust), seria algo como [`std::fs::read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_to_string.html). Nesse caso, trata-se de uma função chamada `read_to_string`, interior ao módulo `fs` que, por sua vez, é interior ao módulo `std`.

#### Então para que serve o `use`?

Já vou dizer o que o `use` não é. O `use` não é um mecanismo para importar módulos. Isso significa que o `use` não serve para trazer nada de novo ao escopo. Tanto é que, se você tentar usar `use` com algo que não está no escopo, dará erro.

O `use` serve para **encurtar** o [**caminho**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-03-paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree.html) a membro(s) de um módulo.

Em relação ao exemplo do começo da pergunta, se, em `main.rs`, fosse utilizada a função `math::add` várias vezes, seria repetitivo ter que digitar `math::add` toda vez. Nesse caso, poderia-se fazer:

```
mod math; // Define o módulo `math` com os membros de `math.rs`.

// Elevo o "escopo" de `add`. Note que estou, essencialmente,
// encurtando o caminho até o membro (no caso, função) `add`:
use math::add;

// Agora posso chamar como:
math::add(1, 2); // Válido, caminho completo. OU:
add(1, 2); // Também válido (caminho encurtado definido pelo `use`).
```

Repare que, ao fazer `use math::add`, encurta-se o caminho para acessar a função `add`. Agora, não mais preciso prefixar com `math::`. Apenas `add` já basta.

Em relação ao `std::fs::read_to_string`, geralmente o programador faz isto:

```
use std::fs;

// Pode utilizar como:
std::fs::read_to_string("./Cargo.toml");
fs::read_to_string("./Cargo.toml"); // Faz uso do encurtamento criado pelo `use` acima.
```

Mas também poderia ser:

```
use std::fs::read_to_string;

// Pode utilizar como:
std::fs::read_to_string("./Cargo.toml");
read_to_string("./Cargo.toml"); // Faz uso do encurtamento criado pelo `use` acima.
```

Então, o `use` (mais detalhes [aqui](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/use-declarations.html)) pode ser utilizado como meio para encurtar caminhos de módulos. Em suma, com ou sem o `use`, ainda seríamos capazes de acessar a função `read_to_string`. A diferença é que o `use` nos permite abreviar esse caminho. É extremamente útil quando utilizamos o mesmo caminho várias vezes e se quer evitar repetições.

Não se pode utilizar `use` em algum nome que não existe no escopo atual.

É por isso que deu erro (conforme mostrado na pergunta) fazer isto:

```
use foo;
```

O que é `foo`?

É necessário a existência um módulo `foo` definido no escopo para abreviar o caminho a um de seus membros.

Faltou uma definição `mod foo` antes do `use foo`. Ou uma Crate `foo` definida como dependência do projeto.

Crates têm seu nome mais superior definido para todos os módulos do projeto. É por isso que se pode utilizar, por exemplo, `use std::fs` sem fazer um `mod std` antes. A `std` é uma Crate padrão do Rust. Todas as Crates que você define como dependência do projeto também são expostas a seus módulos.

---

## TL;DR

O que traz um novo nome ao escopo é o `mod`, e não `use`. O `use` não importa nada.

Você precisa definir, com a diretiva `mod`, os módulos que você vai usar. Crates, como o `std` do Rust ou as que você define como dependência do projeto, são definidas automaticamente pelo Cargo.

O `use` é utilizado para abreviar um caminho que leva a um item de algum módulo.

Comment: Excelente resposta! Então a comparação com o `import` do Pyhon só faz sentido com  `mod` pois é só o `mod` que realmente adiciona o módulo no escopo. Isso quer dizer que o mais próximos que poderíamos comparar o `use` com o Python seria na forma `import mod.func as func` que apenas corresponde ao uso de `mod` e `use` juntos, correto?

Comment: Sim, @fernandosavio, não sou ávido conhecedor de Python, então não posso responder comparativamente com certeza, mas acho uma comparação justa. E sim, é o `mod` que, de fato, traz algo _novo_ ao escopo. Uma analogia para o `use` é "desenterrar" algo que se encontra dentro de algum módulo já presente no escopo (importado "implicitamente", como Crates, ou módulos importados explicitamente via `mod`).

Comment: Cara não consigo aprender isso nem a pal. Tenho um arquivo em src/user/entity/user.rs e no meu arquivo src/main.rs não consigo usar mod user e muito menos mod::user::entity::user por nada... Importar um arquivo deveria ser mais simples...